# How do I use PKCS1_PSS_PADDING with Ruby's RSA implementation?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rsa

According to the [docs for OpenSSL](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-boringssl-docs/rsa.h.html#RSA_private_encrypt), `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` is supposed to be available for use with OpenSSL's `RSA_private_encrypt` function, which is what Ruby uses internally for `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA#private_encrypt`.

Relevant quote from the linked docs for OpenSSL's `RSA_private_encrypt`:

> The padding argument must be one of the `RSA_*_PADDING` values. If in doubt, `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` is the most common but `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` is preferred for new protocols.

Is there anyway I can use PSS padding for the private key encryption? I'd prefer to use PSS over Ruby's default padding (OpenSSL docs say it's preferable), but it seems like PSS is not widely implemented, unless I'm misunderstanding things.

I have Ruby 2.5 and OpenSSL 1.0.2 installed.

```
require 'openssl'

padding = 6 # OpenSSL's raw constant for RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING since Ruby doesn't define it
priv = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
pub = priv.public_key

data = 'foo-bar-baz'
enc = priv.private_encrypt data, padding
dec = pub.public_decrypt enc, padding

puts dec == data
```

Running this throws an error: `unknown padding type`, even though I thought OpenSSL supports the `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` padding type.

Does Ruby 2.5 not support `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation that you refer to mentions that

> `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` can only be used via the EVP interface.

The Ruby functions that you invoke use the [`RSA_private_encrypt()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html) function under the hood, which is not the EVP interface. As a result, OpenSSL emits an error. You can see it happen in the OpenSSL source code [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0/crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c#L262).

However, Ruby's [`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html) exposes two methods specifically for signing and verifying with the RSA-PSS scheme, called `sign_pss()` and `verify_pss()`. Their documentation comes with coding examples showing you how to use them.

RSA-PSS can only be used for signature generation (and verification), [which is not the same as RSA encryption with a private key (and decryption with a public key)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-with-a-private-key-the-same-as-signature-generation).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, and for the links to the `_pss` Ruby methods. Does that mean BoringSSL (a fork of OpenSSL by Google and the lib I mistakingly linked to thinking it was OpenSSL) does things a bit different? Because from [their docs](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-boringssl-docs/rsa.h.html#RSA_private_encrypt), RSA-PSS is able to be used for encryption with a private key/decryption with a public key, and not just for `sign`/`verify` (so BoringSSL supports RSA-PSS for `verify_restore`). Is this a missing feature in OpenSSL compared to BoringSSL?

Comment: No, RSA-PSS is a scheme to use for signing and verification purposes only -- by design.The name already says it: PSS stands for Probabilistic *Signature* Scheme. The documentation you refer to seems somewhat misleading, depending how you interpret it.

Comment: This answer might be interesting for you to read: [What is RSA OAEP & RSA PSS in simple terms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183179/what-is-rsa-oaep-rsa-pss-in-simple-terms).

Comment: Thanks for the link. So in that case shouldn't RSA-PSS padding theoretically be available for `EVP_PKEY_verify_recover`, and as such also in `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA#public_decrypt`, or even a new `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA#public_decrypt_pss` method, if it was updated to utilize the `EVP` interface? (Since most implementations of `private_encrypt`/`public_decrypt` use the `RSA_sign`/`RSA_verify_recover` functions under the hood.) If that's incorrect, then why _can't_ RSA-PSS support the `verify_recover` op?

Comment: The RSA-PSS scheme itself does not have message digest recovery so you will find no implementation of `{RSA|EVP_PKEY}_verify_recover()` that will give it. See also [RSA vs DSA Digital Signature Message Digest Recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87235/rsa-vs-dsa-digital-signature-message-digest-recovery)

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification and for the link. I think BoringSSL's docs really confused me, since they make it sound like RSA-PSS does somehow support recovery, but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere online.